# How can I validate array input?

Tags: java

```
package javaapplication90;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication90 {

  public static int row;
  public static int col;
  public static int matries[][];
  public static int i, j;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    araies();
  }

  public static void araies() {
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("insert the numbers of row");
    row = c.nextInt();
    System.out.println("insert the numbers of col");
    col = c.nextInt();
    matries = new int[row][col];

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {

        matries[i][j] = c.nextInt();
      }
      break;
    }
    System.out.println("the result of array");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {

      for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

        System.out.println(matries[i][j]);
      }

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make a condition so that if the number of rows or columns is not equal to the length of the array array, then break.  For example, if `row` is 3 and `col` is 3, and if user enters

```
123456
458
458
```

then I want to throw an exception, because the length of col array is not equal to length of col array.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what is being asked here. How do you know when the user is done entering numbers?

Comment: if user insert row=3  and col =3     and then insert the values array  if user insert   123  456 789   this is true   if user insert  12345   458 789   display error because user must  insert 3 columns

Comment: Please edit your title to give some indication as to your problem.

Comment: If you need `row` to be equal to `col`, why ask for the two separately? Why not just reuse the same value for both?